# Returning references nested a few methods deep inside RefCell

Tags: rust

I am able to get my reference fine until the Inner object. inner.get_bar() works fine. How do it return the same reference with Outer. I have tried a few things based on the reading but would appreciate the help.

foo_addr is some address in memory that is passed from outside.

attempt1 rightfully fails with temporary value created here.
attemt2, attempt3 cause lifetime issues and requires that Inner must outlive the Bar and also complain about the temporary value due to the reference to inner.

```
use alloc::rc::Rc;
use core::cell::{Ref, RefCell};
use owning_ref::RefRef;

struct Outer {
    inner: Rc<RefCell<Inner>>,
}

impl Outer {
    pub fn new(foo_addr: usize) -> Self {
        Self {
            inner: Rc::new(RefCell::new(Inner::new(foo_addr))),
        }
    }

    pub fn get_bar(&self, idx: usize) -> Result<&Bar, SomeErr> {
        todo!()
    }

    pub fn get_bar_attempt1(&self, idx: usize) -> Result<&Bar, SomeErr> {
        self.inner.borrow().get_bar(idx)
    }

    pub fn get_bar_attempt2(&self, idx: usize) -> Ref<'_, Result<&Bar, SomeErr>> {
        Ref::map(self.inner.borrow(), |inner| &inner.get_bar(idx))
    }

    pub fn get_bar_attempt3(&self, idx: usize) -> RefRef<Inner, Result<&Bar, SomeErr>> {
        RefRef::new(self.inner.borrow()).map(|inner| &inner.get_bar(idx))
    }
}

struct Inner {
    foo_addr: usize,
}

impl Inner {
    fn new(foo_addr: usize) -> Self {
        Self { foo_addr }
    }

    fn get_bar(&self, idx: usize) -> Result<&Bar, SomeErr> {
        let foo = self.get_foo()?;
        foo.get_bar(idx)
    }

    fn get_foo(&self) -> Result<&Foo, SomeErr> {
        let foo = unsafe { &*(self.foo_addr as *const Foo) };
        Ok(foo)
    }
}

#[repr(C)]
struct Foo {
    bar_list: [Bar; 10],
}

impl Foo {
    fn get_bar(&self, idx: usize) -> Result<&Bar, SomeErr> {
        Ok(&self.bar_list[idx])
    }
}

#[repr(C)]
struct Bar {
    val: u32,
}

impl Bar {
    pub fn getter(&self) -> u32 {
        self.val
    }

    pub fn setter(&mut self, new_val: u32) {
        self.val = new_val
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum SomeErr {}
```

Comment: Have you read [How do I return a reference to something inside a RefCell without breaking encapsulation?](/q/29401626/2189130) The answer is you can't return a bare reference to a value derived from within a `RefCell`, a `Ref` must be alive and guarding the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Ref::filter_map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.Ref.html#method.filter_map). Since it requires an `Option` and not a `Result` this is quite clunky, but it works:

```rust
pub fn get_bar(&self, idx: usize) -> Result<Ref<'_, Bar>, SomeErr> {
    let mut err = None;
    Ref::filter_map(self.inner.borrow(), |inner| match inner.get_bar(idx) {
        Ok(value) => Some(value),
        Err(error) => {
            err = Some(error);
            None
        }
    })
    .map_err(|_| err.unwrap())
}
```